# Two UILabels rendered differently in retina and non retina iPhone displays

Tags: ios, uilabel, retina-display

I have designed an interface in a NIB which has two UILabels. The labels are in close proximity to highlight one particular word in a different colour.

The issue is that on a non retina display the two labels render as desired. See Image 1:

[image]

However on a retina display the label for the white text overlaps some of the blue text. See Image 2:

[image]

Note that the frame of the white text label doesn't seem to have moved rather the issue seems to be the word wrap on the blue text label.

Has anyone seen this before and figured out a quick/ painless cure?

Comment: Looks like a possible bug or edge case with the larger label's size. What happens if you widen it by a single point?

Comment: How about sharing some code?  Hard to find the issue in it if we can't see it.

Comment: That is exactly what it is - can you put your comment in an answer so I can mark you up. Thanks!

Comment: @Hugo - it really is all in the NIB. Anyway - jrturton got it in one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting as an answer as requested:

This looks like a possible bug or edge case with the larger label's size. If you widen it by a single point, it may wrap correctly on both devices. It may be worth reporting this as a bug, since the objects should behave identically on retina and non-retina devices.

This will be a non-issue for you in iOS 6, anyway :)

Comment: Check out the WWDC 2012 videos. You won't need two labels to have different coloured words!